# Can sync grpc tell me how many requests are not handled?

Tags: c++, grpc

In grpc 1.26.0(not necessary), c++ server(necessary).

I just build a sync grpc server with ResourceQuota'MaxThreads set. If clients requests too frequently, there will be some requests not be executed.

How can I get the number and the suspending time of these requests? Or is there some metrics?

Thank you all.

Comment: Hi, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Darem Thank you, but my problem is not a bug, it just described a fact and seek help for some (probably) config.